# ArcGIS Linear Referencing successive overlay operations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, linear-referencing

I have 8 tables with RouteID, BeginMeasure and EndMeasure.  I want to successively overlay them starting with the first two and then overlaying the result and the next table then the result of that overlay and the next table until all tables have been run.  I am doing UNION as overlay type.  For some reason when I get to the 4th overlay the tools stops overlaying and just seems to start appending.

If two records have the same measure range and all other values are ok the operation doesn't seem to combine the records.  Are Null vs blank strings considered conflicts for unioning records?

EDIT: The steps are are to use the Result of the first overlay and as the input table and the next table to be overlayed as the overlay table (second parameter).  Is there an ArcMap memory issue?  What is the difference between the input table and the overlay table other than just attribute ordering?

EDIT 2: Looks like there may be memory issues in Arcmap.  After testing/executing 6 or 7 overlays with different datasets it seemed to break down and not want to work.  Closed ArcMap and re opened and started working again.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include precise details of the steps that you are performing, please?  This should include some sample rows from each of the three working tables and from the first one that does not work as you expect.

Comment: Made some edits.  What are you thinking as far as sample data issues?  I've removed all guid fields except for the RouteID field and have one date field.

Answer (score 1):

The answer seems to be that the Overlay tool in the Linear Referencing toolbox does not like GUID data type fields as the Route ID field.  The solution was to transfer the Route ID field which is a guid to a string field.  All is working with the Route ID field as a string data type.